# Square to round.

Tags: geometry

I have a question regarding surface development or the net of a shape.

Suppose you had a truncated cone that transitioned from a circle at the top with for example a radius of $50$ mm to a square base with sides of $200$ mm and height of the piece is $150$ mm. My question is if you flattened this shape out will the curved part of the pattern be part of a perfect circle? My guess is that it would form a circular arc of length $100 \pi$ mm but obviously not create a full circle rather a part of a circle of greater radius.

What would be the relationship between the original radius and the flattened development?

[image]

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "flatten". There are various operations that can be described as flattening. Different operations distort the original shape in different ways. It also depends on how the exactly the "truncated cone" is shaped. Your description does not make it clear. The diagram suggests answers to these questions, but that is only a "suggestion", not something clearly indicated in the diagram.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your reply. What I meant by flatten is the surface development you could cut out of paper and fold it in such a way to make the 3d shape. A sort of flat pattern which sheet metal workers for instance would be familiar with. In particular I was wondering if in the drawing the bottom right figure shows a part of a true circle ( the part with letters A to M and back to A ). If it does I was curious as to what relation that circle has to the circle of the 3d piece. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Steven, Upon further examination of the problem I have tentatively revised my answer, but remain somewhat baffled.  Is the sheet metal cooperating or protesting?

Comment: Hello Edward. Thanks again for your time on this matter it has been invaluable. I attempted this today and had to do it in two halves because it was hard to configure the piece around the tooling of the brake without collisions. It seemed to work but only when I made the radius QA around 108mm and not the 158.113883 that we both thought. I have no clue as why I have had to modify the radius in such a way. If this was a truncated cone it would exhibit a constant slope angle from its base to the top. The square to round doesn't share this property. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: Edward here is a little sketch of how I drew out and cut the sheet metal 
 to make the square to round. Like I said I had to do it in half. Also the circular part didn't quite come out as Pi * R but it was very close. I arrived at this by simply trial and error and still don't have any understanding as to how I can establish what the radius of the circular part ought to be. The sketch is elimentary but I hope you can see it and read it ok.    https://1drv.ms/b/s!AgRrmb7twuZaoDyjTIrFXPDtLPpl?e=AWo4va

Comment: @Edward. Here is the square to round I made earlier this week. It looks a little rustic as I only had an hour or so during lunch to mark it out, cut and shape it LOL. It has a height of 150mm and a base of 200 square with a radius very close to the 50mm desired in my initial design.  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgRrmb7twuZaoD-3nPeyioQMKaaP?e=RIaDPt

Comment: @Steven, Very nice piece. Dimensions all good, including triangle base angle =57.7 degrees. Perhaps the radius of the circular part is QA=158mm after all, and I shouldn’t worry that the angle at Q comes out to 140 degrees.  Sector AQA is not part of your piece of metal anyway. If it were, I suspect things wouldn’t work—you couldn’t have an untruncated cone/pyramid sharing the same vertex. In the finished piece, lines from the corners of the square meet at a point lower than Q, where lines from the mid-points of the sides meet. Right? Shall we say the arc belongs to a circle with radius 158mm?

Comment: @Edward. I can't seem to make the geometry fit using QA at 158mm. In the following sketch using QA as the radius 158mm and to satisfy the arc length of Pi * R ( remember this is half the finished piece ) the angle B has to be 56.92. When setting it out this way and keeping the base at 200 mm you can see that some of the lines and angles don't come out right. In the sketch the red and yellow lines should be the same length but they are out by some 9mm or so. Also angle A ought to be 90 degrees but it comes out at only 84 degrees. https://1drv.ms/b/s!AgRrmb7twuZaoEJCC3Zm_6b4P_Gz?e=96ISZ3

Answer (score 1):

Like $AR$ already drawn, draw perpendiculars $DN$, $GO$, $KP$ to the midpoints of the remaining sides of the square base, and extend them upward to concurrence at $Q$, as in the figure below. Points $R$, $N$, $O$, $P$, lie on the circle with radius $100$ inscribed in the square and parallel to the original circle. Thus $QR=QN=QO=QP$, and $AR=DN=GO=KP$, and hence $Q$ is the center of the circle thru  points $A$, $D$, $G$, $K$.

Since the intermediate points also lie on the original circle, then if all lengths are preserved in the flattening, it appears the remaining points $B$, $C$, $E$, $F$, $H$, $J$, $L$, $M$  must also lie on the circle with center $Q$ and radius $QA$.
[image: flattened cone-like structure]

The following may help to confirm this. $ABCDS$ and its three equal counterparts is the flattened surface of a portion of the oblique cone whose base is the original circle, whose altitude, as shown later, is equal to that of the cone with vertex $Q$ and original circle as base, and whose vertex is a vertex of the square, offset from base center $W$ by distance $ZS=100\sqrt 2$. This appears more clearly in the unflattened figure below.
[image: portion of oblique cone]
Cutting the surface of this oblique cone from base to vertex along the two straight lines $AS$, $DS$ which meet the base $45^o$ on either side of the shortest straight line (e.g. $SY$ in the first figure), and flattening that portion of the surface, yields a circular sector unlike that of a right cone, which is concave toward the sector's vertex, but rather one like $ABYCDS$ (first figure), with circular arc $ABYCD$ convex toward the vertex.

Again then, all points $ABCDEFGHJKLM$ in the flattened figure lie on a circle whose radius $QD$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle (second figure) whose base is the radius $WD$ of the original circle and whose height $QW$ is given by the proportion$$\frac{QW}{WD}=\frac{QZ}{ZN}=\frac{QW}{50}=\frac{QW+WZ}{100}=\frac{QW+150}{100}$$
so that $QW=WZ=150$, and hence $$QD=\sqrt{50^2+150^2}=50\sqrt{10}=r\sqrt {10}$$where $r=WD$ is the radius of the original circle. This is an instance of the general rule that$$\sqrt{x^2+(nx)^2}=x\sqrt{n^2+1}$$where here $x=r$ and $n=3$.

**Reconsideration:**
However, the first figure is not a flattened version of the original structure, as appears from the following. Since $SN=100$ and $DN=QD=50\sqrt {10}$, then$$\angle DSN=\arctan 1.58\approx 57.69^o$$And since $QN=100\sqrt {10}$, then $$\angle QSN=\arctan 3.16\approx 72.45^o$$Therefore$$\angle ASD=2(72.45-57.69)\approx29.52^o$$and in the heptagon $QRSTUVR'$,$$\angle RQR'=900-8\times 57.69^o-4\times 29.52^o-2\times 90^o\approx140.4^o$$Thus arc $ADGKA'\ne100\pi$ after all, i.e. sector $QADGKA'$ is not the flattening of a right cone with base radius $50$, height $150$, and slant side $50\sqrt{10}$, since the sector angle of that cone flattened $\approx 113.84^o$.

On the other hand, if we re-construct the first figure with $\angle AQA'=113.84^o$, as in the figure below,
[image: When angle AQA'=113.84 degrees]

then since radius $QR=100\sqrt{10}$ is unchanged, but the angle at $Q$ is smaller, it is clear that the perimeter of the square base $RS+ST+TU+UV+VR'<800$. Specifically, since $\angle DQG = \angle \frac {AQA'}{4}=28.46^o$, then $\angle TQO=14.23^o$, and$$TO=\tan14.23^o\times QO=.254\times 100\sqrt{10}=80.32$$making the side of the square base $TU=160.64<200$.

Thus it now seems that a 3-dimensional structure whose base is a square with side $200$, whose top is a circle of diameter $100$, and whose height is $150$, cannot be constructed by bending and creasing a flat 2-dimensional shape. If we begin with the correct sector $AQA'$, the flat shape yields a circular top with diameter $100$ but a square base with side less than the expected $200$. If we begin with the structure having circular top of diameter $100$ and square base of side $200$, and flatten it out, we get, as in my first figure, too great an angle at $Q$, i.e. a circular arc $>100\pi$. Is it right to conclude, then, that the structure cannot be flattened without stretching/distortion, and conversely, that no flat shape can yield the desired structure?

Comment: Two further questions if you don’t mind Edward. Is QR twice the value of QA? And how would you go about working out the angle of the whole sector? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, since $QW=WZ$, then $QA=AR$, making $QR=2QA$. I agree with you, that the circular arc $=100\pi$. So if new radius $QD=50\sqrt{10}$, then the circumference of the whole circle $=\pi d=100\pi\sqrt{10}$, making the arc, i.e. the angle, of the sector $=\frac{360^o}{\sqrt{10}}\approx 113.84^o$. Does that seem right?

Comment: Thank you so much Edward for your answers. Very well written and clear.

Comment: Yes Edward the angle seems correct to me. I plan to mark it and cut it out of some sheet metal and then see if it works. I have access to a brake and so can bend the angles with some degree of accuracy. The old method of drawing out the plan first and then transferring them line by line to attain true length can be very time taking. I plan to simply draw out two arcs of radius QA and QR and then divide the arc of QA into equal spacing to act as my fold line. I will then use the arc QR to give me the square base sizes. Thanks again for your help in this.

Comment: Maybe try it with paper first, before biting into sheet metal?  I’m still a bit uneasy that the sketch, which I tried to make close to scale, yields an arc quite a bit greater than $113.84^o$.  I want to check it with paper. Let me know how it goes for you.